# Organize node_modules by parent module

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I used Express generator to create an express app. However, my `node_modules` is populated with all of express's dependencies in the outer level for example:

```
accepts              ee-first           methods         range-parser
array-flatten        escape-html        mime            raw-body
basic-auth           etag               mime-db         send
express ... and many more
```

How can I automatically organize it such that all modules that are dependencies of `express` move under a file named `express` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be running with `npm3` which flattens your dependency tree (unlike the v2). This is now the way it is.

Resources: https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3